# what are advantages of northbridge chipset

Tags: chipset

Historically, what are advantages of having a northbridge chipset as a separate component (from CPU) in a computer motherboard?  And if it has such advantage, why new processor integrate some of its features into CPU?

Comment: Answered here, but I could see this getting a response over at SuperUser as well.

Comment: Advantages over what? Not having one?

Comment: @duskwuff I edited the question.  Hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage of having a "northbridge" in your system is that it allows the CPU to communicate with the rest of the system. Without it, nothing would happen at all. The CPU communicates with the northbridge via the high-speed FSB ([front-side bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-side_bus)), and everything else (memory, network, video, PCIe, etc.) connects to the northbridge via more specialized buses.

Systems are divided in this fashion because there isn't enough area to put all of the required transistors onto a single chip. The yields would be too low and the prices too high as a result. Put another way, in order to get the performance that people want, ALL of the available area on the CPU chip is devoted to processor cores and high-speed cache memories.

Comment: Historically, yes. Today, the northbridge is entirely integrated into the cpu. Even the southbridge is getting sucked in on many chips, which is why they're now getting called SOCs.

Answer (score 6):

The integration you speak of is the move of the memory controller (historically on the northbridge) onto the CPU die, and that is for performance reasons. AMD was the first to really deploy an integrated-memory controller with their Athlon 64, which was a huge step in the market (at least for the mass-market x86 machines, as pointed out in a comment below, others had integrated the memory controller prior).

Moving on-die greatly reduces the latency of memory accesses and reduces the electrical length to get to the controller. Intel followed suit with Nehalem and newer and neither manufacturer has gone back since.

The northbridge also used to support such functions as PCI or AGP connectivity, but with the move to PCI Express, the root complex is also moved onto the CPU die for performance increases, as well as increasing integration (one less large IC and support circuitry to put on a motherboard == lower costs).

Without a northbridge, you'd essentially be creating something akin to a microcontroller where everything is tied together on the same die. With the complexity of a x86 CPU, it's not practical to place fixed functions on the same die as the CPU (integrated GPUs took awhile to move onto the die as well), especially since unlike a microcontroller vendor, you can't make 100 different SKUs to cover all the possible features users may want.

Nowadays, there are many SoC (system-on-chip)-esque variants of x86 CPUs sold where even the southbridge has been integrated into the same physical package, though not the same die. The southbridge now generally handles the 'rest' of the common interfaces in a CPU -- Ethernet, LPC, USB, SATA, additional PCIe lanes, etc. Additionally, BIOS/EFI boot memory is generally interfaced through the southbridge as well.

For Intel platforms anyway, the southbridge <-> CPU link is DMI, which is electrically similar to PCI Express, but with a different protocol layer on top.

Comment: Athlon64 was first only in the mainstream x86 market ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_controller#History) mentions DEC Alpha 21066 and HP PA-7300LC). Integration can also reduce system cost but constrains system diversity by tying more aspects to the chip vendor (system vendors using merchant CPUs have less opportunity to differentiate their products). A distinct memory controller can also be connected to two processor sockets, providing small-scale UMA. A shared I/O and memory interface includes the usual shared vs. partitioned tradeoffs.

Comment: Thanks for the note -- updated to mention that Athlon 64 was just the first in the mainstream market. Never had an opportunity to use the Alphas :)